# access jquery/javascript variable in velocity template

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity, confluence

I'm trying to get velocity and a script to pass in and return a variable.

```
#set ( $test = "" ) 
...
<script>
    var someVariable = '';
    [some stuff happens and someVariable gets set]
    #set ( $test = someVariable )
</script>
...
$test
```

And the above '$test' would print out the whatever someVariable was set as.

How can I export a variable from inside a script tag and give it back to velocity template to work with?

For more context, I've been trying to create a dropdown macro in confluence by following [this](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/13416749/creating-a-dropdown-user-macro). I want to be able to use the saved drop down item and use that to modify some other macro I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Velocity is a server-side compiled template language, while JavaScript is executed on the client side. By the time your JavasScript runs, the Velocity code has already been compiled, transformed into HTML, and sent to the client, so you can't do what you want directly.

Instead, you will need to modify the DOM directly. For example, using jQuery:

```
...
<script>
    var someVariable = '';
    [some stuff happens and someVariable gets set]
    jQuery(".myClass").text(someVariable);
</script>
...
<div class="myClass">&nbsp;</div>
```

Additionally, you will want to make sure that your JavaScript doesn't run until [after the DOM is fully loaded](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) (or using the Atlassian-specific `AJS.toInit()`).